# Why isn't my code working? (TeamTreeHouse)

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code isn't working from a challenge in teamtree house

```
var input1 = prompt("Choose an integer");
var bottomNumber = parseInt(input1);
var input = prompt("choose a second integer");
var topNumber = parseInt(input);
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (topNumber - bottomNumber + 1)) + bottomNumber;
var message = "<p>" + randomNumber + " is a number between " + bottomNumber "and " + topNumber + ".</p>";
document.write(message);
```

I tried to Create a program that has 2 prompts both asking for integers then the it creates a random number betweeen the 2 numbers but on the website the prompts do not appear at all and the javaScript Console has the error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Missing `+` in `bottomNumber "and "` -> `bottomNumber + "and "`

Comment: thanks post it as a question and ill vote for it, i feel so silly now since i spent like half an hour trying to look for my mistake.

Comment: I won't add it as an answer as I've voted to close this question caused by a simple typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var input1 = prompt("Choose an integer");
var bottomNumber = parseInt(input1);
var input = prompt("choose a second integer");
var topNumber = parseInt(input);
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (topNumber - bottomNumber + 1)) + bottomNumber;
var message = "<p>" + randomNumber + " is a number between " + bottomNumber + "and " + topNumber + ".</p>";
document.write(message);
```

Try to interpret the error that appears in the console for a better idea.
The issue was missing a '+' and opening up the browser console will pretty much indicate that.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `+` in your string building.

```
var message = "<p>" + randomNumber + " is a number between " + bottomNumber + "and " + topNumber + ".</p>";
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wLpyzwLL/